# Transforming Ajax codes to Long Polling or Socket.io

Tags: javascript, ajax, sockets, socket.io

I have a website which has many ajax codes and my CPU usage always going to 100%. After research I learned that traditional ajax codes consuming too much CPU and I decided to transform my codes to Long Polling or Socket.io.

Unfortunately I have not much knowlodge about Ajax and Javascript.

So as knowing that you guys are expert with this I want to ask which would be easier to transform my codes.

Ajax to Long Polling or
Ajax to Socket.io

Also is there any guide that I could use for transform proccess?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *"I learned that traditional ajax codes consuming too much CPU"* - That's bullshit. Badly implemented programs consume too much CPU, Ajax is not the root of your problem.

Comment: My webppage is refreshing around 5 or 6 php file every second. Do you think it is not about it?

Comment: A few questions come to mind immediately: *Why* does your page refresh 6 things every second? Can they be combined? Does it really have to be every second? How much data is sent across every time? Can the amount of data be reduced? How much time does your page need to process the data? Can this time be reduced? Research where the processing time actually goes before blaming Ajax.

Comment: It is a raffle website so it has to refresh every second. Is there any way we can talk personally so I could explain you and maybe you could help me?

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. :) I understand that you would prefer one-on-one interactive counseling, but this would go beyond the scope of this site. Especially since the problem you pose here seems to be rather extensive, even more so since you admit that you don't know a lot about JS and Ajax in the first place. Read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to get an idea about what SO questions are supposed to look like. I'm afraid you will have to analyze your code yourself and get yourself to a point of knowledge where you can ask specific questions about parts of it.